# Solr with Client C++ application

Tags: java, c++, solr, server

I have a C++ application.I need to use Solr to index some document. 
For now, I just create a client java application to connect to my server solr and requested some queries. But for me, i need to integrate solr with my C++ application.
My problem : I don't know how to deploy Solr with my setup C++ application? in others wards, how should i use solr with Clientt C++ Application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solr can be accessed an API,you can use [any](http://casablanca.codeplex.com/) of the existing C++ libraries to consume REST/SOAP based APIs.

You can also try [Apache Lucy](http://lucy.apache.org/)

Comment: I don't know how to deploy Solr with my setup C++ application?